# Packaging Executable JAR with JRE in Eclipse and Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I need to create an executable JAR file with JVM packaged so that any one can run the file without depending on JRE they have.
It is for Windows only, so packaging JVM is fine. 
Can you tell how to do that in Eclipse and also using Ant for automated builds.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to write ANT build script. As I have not idea about your project - I am helpless however you will find good tutorial on ANT (Just Google it)
2. You can package your project in eclipse with below steps
   a) Right Click on project
   b) Select Export - you will see Export window
   c) Select JAR file and hit next
   d) Select JAR File export location and click finish.

Comment: This is fine but how will I package JRE with this.

Comment: You can not package JRE with your package. JRE is environment which helps to run your package. You can create/install JRE environment for package on target server (Window/UNIX).